# Magento 2 SMTP settings

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

I've got a fresh magento 2 installation on a virgin test system, but I can't find the settings for a smtp connection. How do you manage email communication in magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, sorry for that. The problem was that I didn't realise that magento uses the php-mail funtion, which calls the mail-mathod of my debian installation. I first needed to install and configure postfix [(here the tutorial)](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_8&p=mail), and after that the php.ini [tutorial here](http://ubuntu-php-magento.blogspot.de/2013/08/how-to-install-postfix-in-ubuntu-1204.html). Then it worked like intended!

Answer (score 4):

Install extension from [GmailSmtpApp](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp) here and replace `Model/Transport.php` with below changes to configure setting for Gmail SMTP service.

```
<?php
/**
 * Mail Transport
 * Copyright © 2015 MagePal. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MagePal\GmailSmtpApp\Model;



class Transport extends \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp implements \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface
     */
    protected $_message;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param MessageInterface $message
     * @param null $parameters
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        if (!$message instanceof \Zend_Mail) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail');
        }

        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

         $smtpHost = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('system/gmailsmtpapp/smtphost', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
         $smtpConf = array(
            'auth' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('system/gmailsmtpapp/auth', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
            'ssl' => 'SSL',
            'username' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('system/gmailsmtpapp/username', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
            'password' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('system/gmailsmtpapp/password', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
         );
        parent::__construct($smtpHost, $smtpConf);
        $this->_message = $message;


    }

    /**
     * Send a mail using this transport
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function sendMessage()
    {
        try { 
            parent::send($this->_message);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e);
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This plugin is ok for testing. However, in production, it will make your store very slow. The best practice is to send the emails to a queue and dispatch them from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [SMTP on Github](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp). It supports 21 different SMTP servers such as `Gmail, Hotmail, O2 Mail, Office365, Mail.com, Send In Blue, AOL Mail Orange, GMX, Outlook, Yahoo, Comcast, or Custom SMTP` - own SMTP server.

Look Transport.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Smtp
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017 Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     http://mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */
namespace Mageplaza\Smtp\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Mail;
/**
 * Class Transport
 * @package Mageplaza\Smtp\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Mail
 */
class Transport extends \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
{
    const CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP = 'configuration_option';
    const DEVELOPER_GROUP_SMTP = 'developer';
    const GENERAL_GROUP_SMTP = 'general';
    /**
     * @var \Mageplaza\Smtp\Helper\Data
     */
    private $smtpDataHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Mageplaza\Smtp\Model\LogFactory
     */
    private $logFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface
     */
    private $encryptor;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor
     * @param \Mageplaza\Smtp\Model\LogFactory $logFactory
     * @param \Mageplaza\Smtp\Helper\Data $smtpDataHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Mageplaza\Smtp\Model\LogFactory $logFactory,
        \Mageplaza\Smtp\Helper\Data $smtpDataHelper
    )
    {
        $this->registry       = $registry;
        $this->smtpDataHelper = $smtpDataHelper;
        $this->logFactory     = $logFactory;
        $this->encryptor      = $encryptor;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function aroundSendMessage(\Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $config = [];
        if ($this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::GENERAL_GROUP_SMTP, 'enabled')) {
            $message = $this->registry->registry('mageplaza_smtp_message');
            if ($host = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'host')) {
                $this->_host = $host;
            }
            if ($returnPath = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'return_path_email')) {
                $message->setReturnPath($returnPath);
            }
            if ($protocol = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'protocol')) {
                $config['ssl'] = $protocol;
            }
            $port = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'port');
            if ($port) {
                $config['port'] = $port;
                $this->_port    = $port;
            }
            $auth        = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'authentication');
            $this->_auth = $auth;
            $config['auth']     = $auth;
            $config['username'] = $this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'username');
            $config['password'] = $this->encryptor->decrypt($this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::CONFIGURATION_GROUP_SMTP, 'password'));
            $headers    = $message->getHeaders();
            $senderName = strip_tags($headers['From'][0], $message->getFrom());
            if ($config['username'] && $senderName) {
                $message->clearFrom();
                $message->setFrom($config['username'], $senderName);
            }
            if (!empty($config)) {
                $this->_config = $config;
            }
            try {
                if (!$this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::DEVELOPER_GROUP_SMTP, 'developer_mode')) {
                    parent::send($message);
                }
                $this->emailLog($message);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->emailLog($message, false);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
            }
        } else {
            $proceed();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Save Email Sent
     *
     * @param $message
     * @param bool $status
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    private function emailLog($message, $status = true)
    {
        if ($this->smtpDataHelper->getConfig(self::DEVELOPER_GROUP_SMTP, 'log_email')) {
            $log = $this->logFactory->create();
            try {
                $log->saveLog($message, $status);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards