# Error while checkout

Tags: magento2, email

I'm trying to send email to customer email id while he place order
after click checkout I got this error :

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): 5.7.0 Must
>   issue a STARTTLS command first. 3sm1925134pai.48 - gsmtp

What are the possibilities of this error?
plz help guys

Comment: Email sending is not working. Try to use SMTP module https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp. Gmail with SSL settings on Server

Comment: hello @ankit it is extension but i want to do this from custom way

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92860/magento-2-smtp-settings